# Djano UpdateView not rendering modelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a model **assesment** which is related to other models.
i have created a UpdateView, Form based on the model **assesment**.
The problem now is when I render the form in a template, no field is displayed except the submit button, so there is nothing to update.
i only see a submit button with no form fields

[image]

Here designs below

**models.py**

```
class assessment(models.Model):
className = models.ForeignKey(all_class, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
student = models.ForeignKey(students, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
subjectName = models.ForeignKey(allsubject, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
firstCa = models.IntegerField(default=0)
secondCa = models.IntegerField(default=0)
exam = models.IntegerField(default=0)
section = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=section_choices)
term = models.CharField(max_length=100 , choices=term_choices)
session = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.className)
class Meta:
    ordering = ['className']
```

**views.py**

```
class assessmentEntry(UpdateView):
model = assessment
fields = '__all__'
Form_class = AssessmentForm
template_name = 'result/assessmentScore.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('result:index')
```

**Forms.py**

```
class AssessmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = assessment
    fields = ['className','student','subjectName','firstCa','secondCa','exam']
```

**urls.py**

```
 path('assessmentScores/<int:pk>/', assessmentEntry.as_view(), name='assessmentScores'),
```

**template(assessmentScore.html)**

```
<div >
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
        {{ Form.as_p}}
        <button
          type="submit"
          class="px-2 text-white bg-indigo-500 rounded-md  focus:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none">
          Save Scores
        </button>
      </form>
   </div>
```

Please what exactly am I doing wrong? and how do I correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class-based views that inherit from the [**`FormMixin`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin) like a `FormView`, `CreateView`, `UpdateView` and `DeleteView` pass the form object to the template as `form`, not <s>`Form`</s>, so you render this as:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

---

> **Note**: While not necessary, usually URLs are written in *kebab case*, so:
>
> ```
> path('assessment-scores/<int:pk>/', assessmentEntry.as_view(), name='assessmentScores')
> ```